# Eclipse: создать новый экран по клику меню

Tags: меню, android-sdk, eclipse, экран

Собственно написал первое приложение, небольшой справочник, но это не важно, хотел еще добавить страничку с описанием... создал разметку inf.xml, создал клас inf.java

```
package ru.arashvg.spices;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class inf extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inf);
    }
}
```

в главном коде пишу:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Операции для выбранного пункта меню
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainListActivity.this, inf.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Прописал в манифесте:

> **<activity android:name=".inf" android:label="@string/hi"> </activity>**

Программа запускается, но при нажатиии на меню вылетает!

Где ошибся? 
Прошу сильно не пинать, только начал изучать саму яву и андроид...

Лог ошибок:

> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
> start activity
> ComponentInfo{ru.arashvg.spices/ru.arashvg.spices.inf}:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
> content must have a ListView whose id
> attribute is 'android.R.id.list' 09-20
> 08:44:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(601):
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method) 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601): Caused by:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
> content must have a ListView whose id
> attribute is 'android.R.id.list' 09-20
> 08:44:49.644: E/AndroidRuntime(601):
>   at
> android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> ru.arashvg.spices.inf.onCreate(inf.java:11)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
> 09-20 08:44:49.644:
> E/AndroidRuntime(601):    ... 11 more
> 09-20 08:44:53.691: I/Process(601):
> Sending signal. PID: 601 SIG: 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ содержится в приведённом вами же стэктрейсе исключения:

> …
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.arashvg.spices/ru.arashvg.spices.inf}: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'**
>
> …

P.S. И настоятельно рекомендую почитать Java Code Conventions (ну и соответствующие соглашения для Android тоже лишними не будут), поскольку имена классов наподобии `inf` заставляют глаза кровоточить.

Comment: тоесть? наколько я понял гдето ошибся с идентификатором, где именно? и на что поменять... что-то немогу сообразить ((((

Comment: В layout'е (который вы устанавливаете вызовом `setContentView`) необходимо добавить `ListView` с атрибутом `android:id="@android:id/list"`.